# Submit button is not listening to isset handler

Tags: php, forms, events, button, handler

I don't have many instances that PHP craps out on me. But this is surely one of them, I have checked through this for an entire day and figured it might coem from a 3rd party. But a symptom that tells me this error is random is that I cannot even try to set a string variable to post back from the submit. Neither `isset` nor `empty` works to capture the event. When I press the submit, the only thing I see is my txtbox variables get shot up into the URL. but NO validation occurs.

So right now now I have a submit button for a login page as follows:

```
<form action='Login.php' method='post'>
    <table align="center">
        <tr><td>Username</td></tr><tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtUsername"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password</td></tr><tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtPass"/></td></tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btnLogin" ID="btnBlueTemp" value="Sign in!" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="errorLogin"><?php echo $Error;?></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I've called the necessary POSTs and here is the event.

```
$txtUsername = $_POST["txtUsername"];
$txtPass = $_POST["txtPass"];
$btnLogin = $_POST["btnLogin"];
if(isset($btnLogin)){
$Error = "ok";
}
```

What could be causing a problem that is not letting my button handler be caught? I am using Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use submit button to check that the form has been submited.  either add a hidden form field and check that if its set, or use some other mechanism.  You will not have this problem in firefox, but in IE you will.

Comment: This is a known issue? You give me an example of how to do hidden fields?

Comment: Well first time when i came across this i was told that according to rfc you should not rely on the submit button to check that the form has been submitted, i didnt look into irt further just worked around this.
add a hidden field in your form like this:
<input type="hidden" name="form_sent" value="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. When you use `$btnLogin = $_POST["btnLogin"];` , you are actually setting the variable. So your script will get executed even you hit the url from address bar without hitting submit button.

Instead use -

```
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']){
      // do stuff
}else{
      // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: I was using extract($_POST) before, and if I used `$btnLogin = $_POST["btnLogin"];` i am setting the variable. Then when the submit button is clicked, the page postsback with my `$btnLogin` set as true the second time. Isnt this what happens?